Breaking down はそのままに grammar
I need help understanding the usage of はそのままに in this sentence:

この改訂版では、「げんき」の特長である「教えやすさ」はそのままに、私たちの経験や皆様の声を反映させて、新しい内容の追加、改訂を行いました。

I think は plays a contrastive role and そのままに is short for そのままにして. Then 「げんき」の特長である「教えやすさ」はそのままに translates to "keeping 教えやすさ, which is the selling-point of Genki, intact and..." Is that correct?
Here are few more examples from massif.la:

端整な顔立ちはそのままに、美しさに磨きがかかっている。


飄々とした表情はそのままに、その眼光だけが鋭い。


Your analysis seems correct. This type of そのままに sounds nicer without adding して, so in practice, it might be better to remember this as a fixed pattern. Similar expressions include Xとは別に ("separately from X") and Xもそこそこに ("without spending much time on X").
